# How do I concatenate two one-dimensional arrays in NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I have two arrays `A = [a1, ..., an]` and `B = [b1, ..., bn]`.
I want to get new matrix C that is equal to

```
[[a1, b1],
 [a2, b2],
 ...
 [an, bn]]
```

How can I do it using `numpy.concatenate`?

Comment: Look for `np.column_stack`.

Comment: @Divakar Nice! Any intuitions why `np.column_stack` is little bit slower please?

Comment: @kmario23 Well it uses `np.concatenate` under the hoods, so if you are comparing against it, its the function wrapper overhead that we are paying for there.

Answer (score 4):

How about this very simple but *fastest* solution ?

```
In [73]: a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
In [74]: b = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
In [75]: ab = np.array([a, b])
In [76]: c = ab.T

In [77]: c
Out[77]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [3, 4],
       [4, 5],
       [5, 6]])
```

But, as [Divakar pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42909716/how-do-i-concatenate-two-one-dimensional-arrays-in-numpy/42912402#comment72918749_42909716), using [`np.column_stack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html) gives the answer directly like:

```
In [85]: np.column_stack([a, b])
Out[85]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [3, 4],
       [4, 5],
       [5, 6]])
```

---

**Efficiency** (in descending order)

Interestingly, my simple solution turns out to be the fastest. (little faster than [`np.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html), twice as fast as [`np.column_stack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html) and thrice as fast as [`np.vstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html))

```
In [86]: %timeit np.array([a, b]).T
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.44 µs per loop

In [87]: %timeit np.concatenate((a[:,None], b[:,None]), axis=1)
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.6 µs per loop

In [88]: %timeit np.column_stack([a, b])
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.5 µs per loop

In [89]: %timeit np.vstack((a, b)).T
100000 loops, best of 3: 14.7 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `np.vstack` then transpose the matrix after

```
import numpy as np
A = [1, 2, 3]
B = [4, 5, 6]
C = np.vstack((A, B)).T
```

Comment: Since it was asked to use `np.concatenate` I'll just add `C = np.concatenate((A, B)).reshape(2,3).T` here.

Comment: oh, that's right! thanks @Michael for updating the solution

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I think your solution is better ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
In [26]: A=np.arange(5)
In [27]: B=np.arange(10,15)
In [28]: np.concatenate((A[:,None], B[:,None]), axis=1)
Out[28]: 
array([[ 0, 10],
       [ 1, 11],
       [ 2, 12],
       [ 3, 13],
       [ 4, 14]])
In [29]: _.tolist()
Out[29]: [[0, 10], [1, 11], [2, 12], [3, 13], [4, 14]]
```

`np.column_stack`, `np.vstack`, `np.stack` all do the same thing, just expanding the dimensions of the arrays in different ways.

`np.stack((A,B),-1)` expands the arrays like I did, with a `newaxis` indexing.

`np.column_stack((A,B))` uses:

```
arr = array(arr, copy=False, subok=True, ndmin=2).T
```

`np.vstack((A,B)).T` uses:

```
concatenate([atleast_2d(_m) for _m in tup], 0)
```

---

As a matter of curiosity, note this `vstack` equivalent:

```
In [38]: np.concatenate((A[None],B[None]))
Out[38]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]])
```